# How to get android log from the users for Android 4.1 without rooting?

Tags: android, logging, sdk, root, ddms

Starting Android 4.1 gettings android log requires ROOT permission, so now it's impossible to
ask users to send log using apps like LogCollector, which just get android log and send it to email. Android log can be viewed using ddms app from Android SDK but it's not good to ask users install Android SDK.

So, how to get android log from the users for Android 4.1 without rooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your own app's log without permission now. You can not read other apps' logs at all, permission or not.

This is somewhat documented [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/6U4A5irWang). Just refer to Diane Hackborn's response:

> The change is that third party applications can no longer get the read
>   logs permission, however every app can read the logs containing only
>   the lines *they* have written, without needing any permission.
>
> Keep in mind that access to the logs has never been part of the SDK,
>   and is still not part of the SDK.  If you are relying on it then, even
>   after this change, you run the risk of breaking in the future.  (And
>   that is partly why this got lost for documentation, it is not part of
>   the SDK, so there isn't really a place to document it, in fact
>   documenting it would kind-of make it a part of the SDK which we don't
>   want. :p)

Comment: And a very good thing too.  I've seen some horrors in logcat, like an app that showed the users password in plain text.  And how many people on SO (or at least the ones who only come once) think "logcat, that's how to debug my app".

Comment: great to know that, but it means that every app now have to include alsmost the same code as LogCollector inside it... not good.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few handy *libraries* out there that send the Crash Reports across to you.

1. [ACRA](http://acra.ch/)
2. [Zubhium](https://www.zubhium.com/) [How it works](https://www.zubhium.com/docs/crashreporting/)
3. [Bug Sense](http://www.bugsense.com/)

Acra is open source and free. Zubhium and Bug Sense have have a limited functionality *Free Version*.

All being said, these are good **ONLY** for your own application. Everything else that does not belong to you, is basically, **off limits**.

I am not sure if this could / would work, but see the Source for [Cyanogenmod](https://github.com/CyanogenMod). There might be something of use and interesting there.

Comment: thanks for the app suggestions. just note that android log is sometimes required not only when the app crashes but when some not critical exception occurs